# Flatten directories with single files

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

I have the following directory structure

```
root_directory
--sub_a
----index.html
--sub_b
----index.html
--sub_c
----index.css
----index.html
```

now I would like to move the file to the parent directory and rename it after their parent folder, but only if they're the only file in the subdirectory.
This should effectively flatten out the directory, like this:

```
root_directory
--sub_a.html
--sub_b.html
--sub_c
----index.css
----index.html
```

Is there a smart way to achieve this?
I can `find . -name 'index.html'` but I'm not sure how to additionally check if the directory includes files other than that.
I guess when I have the list of those files I can move them up (`mv path/index.html ..`) but it's probably smarter to somehow reuse the folder name to rename them before.

Comment: Doesn't really matter for my purposes, I could remove it afterwards with `find . -type d -empty -delete`; I can use rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no sub-directory under `sub_x` directories as when if `sub_x` directory was contain only one regular file but one or more subdirectories or other type of files or symlinks, then they will be removed as you are requested to rename that one file with its parent directory; so, be noted.

```
# !/bin/bash 

find /path/to/root_directory/ -type d -execdir bash -c '
    for file in "$1"/*; do
        [[ -f "$file" ]] && (( $((++filesCount)) > 1 )) && exit 1;
    done;
    ((filesCount==1)) && echo mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}.${file##*.}" && echo rm -r "$1"
' _ {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

dry-run output:

```
mv -v ./sub_b/index.html ./sub_b.html
rm -r ./sub_b
mv -v ./sub_a/index.html ./sub_a.html
rm -r ./sub_a
```

remove `echo`s in the command to perform real action of the `mv` and `rm` commands. result:

```
root_directory
 ├── sub_a.html
 ├── sub_b.html
 └── sub_c
     ├── index.css
     └── index.html
```

---

```
find ... -type d -execdir bash -c '...' _ {} \;
```

`find` only `-d`irectories and execute inline-script `bash -c '...'` ***within*** (usage of the `-execdir` action) each directory it found.

---

```
for file in "$1"/*; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] && (( $((++filesCount)) > 1 )) && exit 1;
done;
```

travers all the files from the directory path returned by the `$1` and checks if that's a `-f`ile then increment a variable and at the same time verifying if its value exceed more than 1 (meaning that directory have at least 2 files), if so then exit from the inline-script and `find` command will read next directory to continue process on; `exit` is used to shorten the process time and do not continue counting files in that directory as it doesn't meet our condition for that directory (directory containing one file only).

---

```
((filesCount==1)) && mv -v "$file" "${file%/*}.${file##*.}" && rm -r "$1"
```

checks if filesCount is equal 1 then rename the file and remove the directory; `${file%/*}` and `${file##*.}` used is known [Shell Parameter-Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).